# Issue with AJAX and displaying multiple html tags

Tags: php, html, mysql, css, ajax

So I am using the code that I got off W3C here: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp

modified it to fit with my file names and database etc, however I am having a weird issue with echoing my responses to look correct.
For every product that collects from the product database it needs to print it in a section tag like so:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
echo "<section class='sideWays'>" . $row['product_ID'] . " " . $row['product_name'] . " " . $row['description'] . " " . "<div class='colHeaderImageRight'>" . '<img src="'.$row['image'].'"">' . "</div>" . "</section>";
}
```

However this code isn't working anymore, the closest I have gotten is it to only display one  and then breaks the rest.

the PHP echo is being returned into the following div tag

```
<article>
<div id="txtHint"><b>Person info will be listed here...</b></div>
</article>
```

so I have tried changing my CSS to stuff like article > .txtHint > #sideWays or even just making the #sideWays css the same as .txtHint to skip the > #sideWays but nothing is working to display my CSS on the echo.

Comment: you have `<img src="...""`. note the extra double-quote. There is **NO** reason to use all that pointless string concatenation. If you want to do "complex" quoted text, then use a [heredoc](http://php.net/heredoc) and skip the string concatentation entirely.

Comment: Isn't working any more? Have you looked in the error logs? Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: It's working on another page where I am just displaying everything with no AJAX, not that I am using AJAX the <section class='sideWays'> is for someone reason not being echoed back / recognised

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why but changing the keyword echo to print fixed the issue of it not recognising my html tags and applying the CSS to them.